# Can't get svg element to follow mouse exactly

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, snap.svg

I'm using Snap svg and I want to position an element so that is always underneath the mouse pointer. I've seen various tuts but nothing seems current (setAttribute isn't in the Snap docs so I've just been using a transform).

This code makes the element follow the mouse with what appears to be some sort of squared relationship between the mouse x,y and the element x,y. Why is this and how do I fix it?

```
    var tree1xy = tree1.getBBox();


park.hover(function() {
    follow();
});

    function follow() {

        map.mousemove( moveFunc );

        function moveFunc( ev, x, y ) {
            tree1.transform('t' + (x - tree1xy.x) + ',' + (y - tree1xy.y) );
        };

    };
```

I have this in the css, but dividing everything by three doesn't seem to fix things:

```
svg {
width: 33%;
height: auto;
}
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/snap.svg-min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


    <div id="map">

    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main2.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you show us the HTML/SVG please?

Comment: Uploaded the html - the svg is huge - will take me a little while to make a smaller version. Sucks I can't just upload it using the image upload :/

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure, but I'm guessing you need an absolute transform instead of a relative one

t=relative transform

T=absolute transform

```js
var s = Snap("#svg")
  , c = s.circle( 10, 10, 10 )
  , coords = document.querySelector('#coords')

s.mousemove(function(ev, x, y) {
  coords.innerText = `${x},${y}`
  var bb = c.getBBox()
    , mx = x - bb.r0
    , my = y - bb.r0
   
  c.transform("T" + mx + "," + my)
})


//t=relative transform, T=absolute transform, s=relative scale, S=absolute Scale
//r=relative rotate, R=relative rotate
//relative means it takes into account previous transforms to accumulate
//here it doesn't make much difference, until we combine later
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg" width="1024" height="1024"></svg>
<div id="coords"></div>
```

**update: modified OP fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/t2qvfLw5/51

```js
var container = Snap('#svg-container')
  , map = container.select("#svg-of-the-park")
  , group = container.select("#group-of-shapes")
  , tree1 = container.select('#tree1')
  , park = container.select('#park')
  , coords = document.querySelector('#coords') // for debug only
  , in_the_park = false
;

park.attr('fillOpacity', '0')

park.hover(
  function mouseInThePark() {
    in_the_park = true
  }, 
  function mouseLeftThePark() {
    in_the_park = false
  }
)

container.mousemove(function(ev, x, y) {
  if (!in_the_park) return

  var bb = tree1.getBBox()
    , p_bb = group.getBBox()
    , pos_x = Math.floor(
      x
      - bb.x
      - p_bb.x
      + container.node.offsetLeft
      )
    , pos_y = Math.floor(
      y
      - bb.y
      - p_bb.y
      - bb.height
      - container.node.offsetTop
    )
  ;
  
  coords.innerText = `${x},${y} => ${pos_x},${pos_y}`
  
  tree1.transform(
    `translate(${pos_x},${pos_y})`);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/snap.svg/0.1.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
 <body>
    <div id="coords">...</div>
  <div id="svg-container">
    
    <!-- notice the svg itself gets an element id -->
      <svg 
        id="svg-of-the-park"
        version="1.1"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        x="0px"
        y="0px"
        width="712.464px"
        height="1000px"
        viewBox="0 0 712.464 900"
        enable-background="new 0 0 712.464 899.955"
        xml:space="preserve"
      >
          <!-- notice also that the group element is not the same as the parent div -->
          <g id="group-of-shapes">
            <polyline id="Large_Triangle" fill="#4E4E4E" points="352.732,31.586 23.392,879.586 673.892,879.586  "/>
            <polyline id="Sm_Triangle" fill="#4E4E4E" points="462.892,272.391 462.892,272.391 693.892,271.891 
            580.401,577.821  "/>
            <polyline id="grass" fill="#9FB718" points="389.79,715.391 472.392,602.391 569.059,602.391 605.21,697.967 
            521.392,815.345 417.555,815.344 389.79,780.891 389.79,715.391  "/>
            <polygon id="tree7" fill="#73850B" points="495.726,796.562 505.892,796.562 505.892,802.062 512.059,802.062 
            512.059,796.562 523.559,796.562 509.642,761.729  "/>
            <polyline id="tree6" fill="#73850B" points="545.729,593.209 533.059,624.058 543.059,624.058 542.892,629.891 
            547.893,629.891 547.975,624.055 558.482,624.055 545.729,593.209  "/>
            <polygon id="tree5" fill="#73850B" points="527.392,677.391 514.892,711.391 524.392,711.391 524.392,716.891 
            530.392,716.891 530.392,711.391 540.892,711.391  "/>
            <polygon id="tree4" fill="#73850B" points="505.726,659.893 495.726,685.726 504.059,685.726 504.059,690.059 
            508.393,690.059 508.393,685.726 516.059,685.726  "/>
            <polygon id="tree3" fill="#73850B" points="501.393,700.06 491.893,724.727 499.559,724.727 499.559,729.227 
            504.059,729.227 504.059,724.727 512.059,724.727  "/>
            <polygon id="tree2" fill="#73850B" points="410.726,748.394 421.559,748.394 421.559,754.061 426.893,754.061 
            426.893,748.394 438.226,748.394 424.476,713.727  "/>
            <polygon id="tree1" fill="#73850B" points="445.726,742.062 435.393,769.514 444.227,769.395 444.226,773.895 
            448.559,773.895 448.559,769.395 457.059,769.229  "/>
            <polygon id="_x3C_Rd_x5F_7_x3E_" fill="#FFF167" points="467.631,272.38 536.892,367.557 639.225,367.557 639.287,271.992 
            650.287,271.992 650.225,367.557 658.402,367.557 654.801,377.266 650.225,377.266 650.225,389.602 639.559,418.354 
            639.559,377.391 536.892,377.266 516.892,413.224 511.892,399.891 524.642,377.141 503.162,377.141 499.475,367.557 
            524.642,367.557 471.479,294.679 462.892,272.391  "/>
            <path id="_x3C_Rd_x5F_6_x3E_" fill="#FFF167" d="M536.559,794.105l11.016-15.427c0,0,0.016,67.879,0.016,68.879
            s75.854-101.22,75.854-101.22l5.303,13.986l-16.084,20.583l30.896,41.984l-8.917,7.151l-29.432-40.151l-24.984,34.333
            l41.695,55.362h-14.333l-34.362-46.362l-33.667,46.362h-13.333l10.333-16.029v-67.333"/>
            <polygon id="_x3C_Rd_x5F_5_x3E_" fill="#FFF167" points="351.56,623.558 351.56,733.894 389.79,733.894 389.79,746.338 
            351.56,746.338 351.56,811.558 340.227,811.558 340.227,642.225  "/>
            <polygon id="_x3C_Rd_x5F_4_x3E_" fill="#FFF167" points="393.227,555.89 399.894,545.89 457.059,623.366 450.185,632.77  "/>
            <polyline id="_x3C_Rd_x5F_3_x3E_" fill="#FFF167" points="134.227,811.558 147.892,812.534 147.892,589.266 158.621,589.33 
            262.894,740.223 269.227,729.227 205.561,638.89 295.561,638.89 295.561,628.223 198.561,628.223 171.894,589.33 279.667,589.33 
            295.561,609.89 295.561,590.89 191.007,448.002 186.12,460.587 270.553,577.821 140.54,577.948 135.408,591.161  "/>
            <polygon id="_x3C_Rd_x5F_2_x3E_" fill="#FFF167" points="310.392,516.891 399.892,516.891 393.227,528.891 310.392,528.891  "/>
            <polygon id="_x3C_Rd_x5F_1_x3E_" fill="#FFF167" points="295.561,381.391 216.877,381.391 212.371,392.994 295.561,392.994  "/>
            <path id="_x3C_Lg_x5F_rd_x5F_top_x5F_curve_x3E_" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M423.499,838.141c0,0,0,0,0-13.75
            s-11.107-12.833-11.107-12.833"/>
            <path id="_x3C_Lg_x5F_rd_x5F_btm_x3E_" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M254.645,833.354H41.347l-5.213,13.424h354.343l-0.149,32.811
            l12.815-0.003c0,0,0.107-20.771,0.107-33.398s-11.107-12.833-11.107-12.833H258.31H254.645z"/>
            <polygon fill="#D3D3D3" points="295.561,178.793 295.561,686.558 262.894,740.223 262.894,811.558 49.812,811.558 44.599,824.981 
            410.726,824.981 410.478,879.586 423.392,879.586 423.499,824.391 412.392,811.558 278.558,811.558 278.558,742.062 
            491.893,397.225 484.522,378.558 310.392,659.893 310.392,140.605  "/>
            <circle id="_x3C_Roundabout_x5F_lg_x3E_" fill="#888888" cx="269.906" cy="830.043" r="28.209"/>
            <circle id="_x3C_Roundabout_x5F_sm_x3E_" fill="#C5C5C5" cx="269.867" cy="830.107" r="15.901"/>
          </g>


          <g id="Locations">

          <polyline id="park" fill="#000000" stroke="none" points="473.707,601.598 389.791,714.644 389.791,781.896 
            417.946,815.345 521.232,815.345 605.21,700.06 568.232,602.896 "/>

          </g>

      </svg>
  </div>

 </body>
```

unfortunately using css scaling does throw it all off, I think it would be easier to handle re-sizing a different way

Comment: I tried this - it didn't work but apparently there is a problem with Snap and absolute transforms?

Comment: This is clearly the right approach but I'm having trouble making this work repositioning my element within my svg - it seems to be defining the location from  . I particularly don't understand the rotating behaviour? I'm afraid I'm pretty new to svg and Snap. It seems that t and T do the same thing for me

Comment: @Davtho1983 if you can show a broken jsfiddle then we might be able to give you more help, the example I pasted appears to work just fine

Comment: There's a few problems with that fiddle. There is no #park element, you have 2 #map id's for example. You are also using a select on a div id (if #map) so you want to make sure you are selecting a unique SVG id (which may be fixed by renaming map upper/lower case to differentiate.

Comment: Hi Ian - there is a #park element - <polyline id="park" fill="#000000" stroke="none" points="473.707,601.598 389.791,714.644 389.791,781.896 
            417.946,815.345 521.232,815.345 605.21,700.06 568.232,602.896 "/>

Comment: The point about selecting divs tho is a good one and I will try to disambiguate my code

Comment: ok I have further simplified the fiddle - any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: I updated your example http://jsfiddle.net/t2qvfLw5/51/ unfortunately using css scaling throws it all off as you say.

Comment: that is awesome - that is exactly what I need - thanks I have been tearing my hair out! Gonna mark this as answered - how do I put your comment as the answer?

Comment: @Davtho1983 i modified my answer to include the updated snip